# Controller's actions in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm making a basic app in MVC.

I have a edit page. That page is feed by the object ID.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

When you see this edit page, a "Save" button is in the bottom.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

So I made a second method that is called to perform changes in DB :

```
public void Edit(MyObject object)
```

I have troubles because they all have the same method name.

So how Can I rename the second method name (that receive the custom object)?
The button must be linked again to the method that perform edition in DB...

Thanks !

Comment: You should not use `object` as a parameter...it is a reserved word I guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with two actions that have the same name.
However, you should add `[HttpPost]` to the POST action.

Comment: Okay, and of I wanted to make a third one method with that same name? not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try with  it

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Edit(MyObject object)
```

or

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("MyOverloadedName")]
    public void Edit(MyObject object)
```